# STm32f401re Nucle Board user button not working

Tags: stm32

I have stm32f401re nucleo board. I am looking at hal library given by stm. I wanted to check the external interrupt on the board so i used BSP function. on pressing the user button(PC13), i want led to toggle. But its not working at all.I modified the GPIO example to use BSP functions. I have override the

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
```

Please correct me.

```
/**


    ******************************************************************************
      * @file    GPIO/GPIO_IOToggle/Src/main.c 
      * @author  MCD Application Team
      * @version V1.2.0
      * @date    26-December-2014
      * @brief   This example describes how to configure and use GPIOs through 
      *          the STM32F4xx HAL API.
      ******************************************************************************
      * @attention
      *
      * <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT(c) 2014 STMicroelectronics</center></h2>
      *
      * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
      * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
      *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
      *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
      *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
      *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
      *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
      *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
      *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
      *      without specific prior written permission.
      *
      * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
      * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
      * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
      * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
      * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
      * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
      * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
      * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
      * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
      * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
      *
      ******************************************************************************
      */

    /* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #include "main.h"

    /** @addtogroup STM32F4xx_HAL_Examples
      * @{
      */

    /** @addtogroup GPIO_IOToggle
      * @{
      */ 

    /* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
    static void SystemClock_Config(void);
    static void Error_Handler(void);

    /* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

    /**
      * @brief  Main program
      * @param  None
      * @retval None
      */
    int main(void)
    {
     /* This sample code shows how to use STM32F4xx GPIO HAL API to toggle PA05 IOs 
        connected to LED2 on STM32F4xx-Nucleo board  
        in an infinite loop.
        To proceed, 3 steps are required: */

      /* STM32F4xx HAL library initialization:
           - Configure the Flash prefetch, instruction and Data caches
           - Configure the Systick to generate an interrupt each 1 msec
           - Set NVIC Group Priority to 4
           - Global MSP (MCU Support Package) initialization
         */
      HAL_Init();

      /* Configure the system clock to 84 MHz */
      SystemClock_Config();

      /* -1- Enable GPIOA Clock (to be able to program the configuration registers) */
    //  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    //
    //  /* -2- Configure PA05 IO in output push-pull mode to
    //         drive external LED */
    //  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    //  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    //  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    //  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST;
    //  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      BSP_LED_Init(LED2);
      BSP_PB_Init(BUTTON_KEY, BUTTON_MODE_EXTI);
      /* -3- Toggle PA05 IO in an infinite loop */  
      while (1)
      {
    //    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
    //
    //    /* Insert delay 100 ms */
    //    HAL_Delay(100);
      }
    }

    /**
      * @brief  System Clock Configuration
      *         The system Clock is configured as follow : 
      *            System Clock source            = PLL (HSI)
      *            SYSCLK(Hz)                     = 84000000
      *            HCLK(Hz)                       = 84000000
      *            AHB Prescaler                  = 1
      *            APB1 Prescaler                 = 2
      *            APB2 Prescaler                 = 1
      *            HSI Frequency(Hz)              = 16000000
      *            PLL_M                          = 16
      *            PLL_N                          = 336
      *            PLL_P                          = 4
      *            PLL_Q                          = 7
      *            VDD(V)                         = 3.3
      *            Main regulator output voltage  = Scale2 mode
      *            Flash Latency(WS)              = 2
      * @param  None
      * @retval None
      */
    static void SystemClock_Config(void)
    {
      RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
      RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;

      /* Enable Power Control clock */
      __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

      /* The voltage scaling allows optimizing the power consumption when the device is 
         clocked below the maximum system frequency, to update the voltage scaling value 
         regarding system frequency refer to product datasheet.  */
      __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

      /* Enable HSI Oscillator and activate PLL with HSI as source */
      RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 0x10;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
      if(HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }

      /* Select PLL as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 
         clocks dividers */
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;  
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;  
      if(HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
    }

    /**
      * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
      * @param  None
      * @retval None
      */
    static void Error_Handler(void)
    {
      while(1)
      {
      }
    }

    #ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
    /**
      * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
      *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
      * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
      * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
      * @retval None
      */
    void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
    { 
      /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
         ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

      /* Infinite loop */
      while (1)
      {
      }
    }
    #endif


    void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
    {
        if( GPIO_Pin == KEY_BUTTON_PIN)
            BSP_LED_Toggle(LED2);
    }
    /**
      * @}
      */

    /**
      * @}
      */

    /************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Answer (score 0):

add this function in in stm32f4xx_it.h

```
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void);
```

and

```
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(KEY_BUTTON_PIN);
}
```

in stm32f4xx_it.c